# Setting defaults for Jekyll collections

Tags: jekyll

For some reason I am unable to set defaults for my Jekyll collections. I *think* I have followed the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) correctly but even setting a default `layout` is alluding me..

Here's what I got:

```
collections:
  work:
    output: true
    permalink: /work/:path/

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
  -
    scope:
      path: "work"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "work"
```

My blog post markdown files are in `/_posts` and my work (collection) markdown files are in `/_work`. In the example above, I want all work items to use the `work` collection. How is this not working?

By the way, I am using Jekyll 3.3.1.

Comment: Can try it out in the moment but a collection is not a page so it should rather be `path: ""`, `type: "yourCollectionName"`, `layout: "yourLayoutFortheCollection"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are referring to pages that have the path 'work', while you want to refer to all items in the collection 'work'. This can be done by only specifying the 'type' (collection) and leaving the path empty, like this:

```
collections:
  work:
    output: true
    permalink: /work/:path/

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "work"
    values:
      layout: "work"
```